# How to use MS UI Automation in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, interop, delphi-2009, microsoft-ui-automation

I have a C# application, which uses Microsoft UI Automation functionality, e. g. a call like `AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(...)`.

Now I need to do the same thing (use MS UI Automation) in Delphi 2009.

How can I

a) declare that my Delphi code uses MS UI Automation library and
b) make calls like `AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(...)`

?

There are several tutorials ([tutorial 1](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32754), [tutorial 2](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/BorCon2004/Interop2/COMNetInterop.htm)) explaining how to package one's own .NET code so that it can be used with Delphi, but in my case I need to use "pre-packaged" (already installed) assembly in Delphi.

**Update 1**

Now I can get access to `AutomationElement.RootElemeent` on one machine, but it doesn't work on another.

How can I find out the reason, why the attempt to execute `uiAutomation := CoCUIAutomation.Create;` fails on the second machine?

Comment: If it's already installed and exposed as COM it should be possible to just use it like any other COM object: import type library etc.

Comment: Can you point me to a tutorial (ideally with code samples) on how import it in Delphi?

Comment: [Importing Type Library Information](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Importing_Type_Library_Information), [How to Import a Type Library from the Command Line](http://chrisbensen.blogspot.de/2007/07/how-to-import-type-library-from-command.html)

Comment: If the type library route does not pan out, the only reliable way I know of to invoke .net assemblies from Delphi is the commercial RemObjects Hydra product, which is very good quality.

Comment: It's exposed in COM in Windows 7 (UIAutomationCore.dll).

Comment: I imported MS UI automation DLL into my Delphi project. How can I access static property `AutomationElement.RootElement` ?

Comment: re update1: The RTL should raise an exception that would hint why it fails. Can you run 'inspect.exe' from SDK tools or similar in the failing machine?

Comment: In the debug output I see a message `CoInitialize not called: GUID=...`. I put `CoInitialize(nil)` into `initialization` section (as some forums recommend), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you have to import the UI Automation type library (COM Object) into your project, this can be done with the "Import Component" wizard (Component -> Import Component) in Delphi 2010.

Microsoft kept the COM Object's interface really close to it's .NET counterpart so you shouldn't have much trouble to use it if you are already familiar with the .NET automation library.