# Run an external application as hide application and control it with Delphi

Tags: delphi

I need run a 3rd application (I think developed with Visual Studio) and hide it (the user don't must see it), then I need:
1. click on a menu to open a window, click on tab component;
2. set 2 edit fields, and choose a item from combobox;
3. click on a button and extract 2 text from 2 edit fields;
4. close the application;

All this without user see nothing. Is it possible in anyway?
I need do it with a Delphi application.

I don't have experience about control of 3rd application an I don't know if it possible.

Comment: You can probably do this with UIAutomation. Better hope the other app does not show dialogs.

Comment: The only thing I think might work in terms of "hiding" but still interacting with the app would be to position it off the visible desktop.

Comment: @Craig I think that some interaction is possible with hidden windows

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Perhaps; but if not, Martin could fall back to the positioning option. As for "hoping the other app does not show dialogs", he does say "click on a menu to open a window". So he'd probably have "click" the menu, then find and hide the new window. If this creates unavoidable flicker, then depending how quickly the  external application does its work, it may be more straight-forward to just do the work and quickly close the app. Of course the flickering may be ugly, but so is this approach to solving the problem.

Comment: @CraigYoung The 3rd application is a very small application and very fast (when I click on button I get the result without lag). There are not dialogs, there are a main form with a menu and when I click on one item of this menu a new window is open. I need control this second window.

Comment: @Martin Unfortunately, I've never done external UI automation. So I'm unable to offer more than the general pointers stated so far. However, if you look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12894215/224704), you might find enough info to make progress.

Comment: Create a hidden top level window, set a global hook, run application, catch window of application and parent it in the hidden window before it is shown. Alternatively remove visible style instead of parenting. I have no idea if any one of these works or not.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz SW_HIDE in STARTUPINFO

Comment: Do you have source code for the VisualStudio application?  Controlling another application in this way is a rather terrible solution that should only be used as an absolute last resort.  Unless that VS program is doing some sort of amazing magic and the source code is lost forever I would consider re-implementing in Delphi or re-compiling the VS application's business logic into a DLL.

Comment: @J... The Visual Studio application is a close source application, so I don't have any other solution. I just have try some others easy way but without solution. This is my last resort.