# Simulating Mouse Clicks within a minimized or inactive form

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe5

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to simulate mouse clicks and such in a window that is minimized or not currently active. In case it's not clear, I want my mouse to be able to click and stuff without actually using the mouse.

For example, while I'm browsing the web I would like my program to be able to be clicking inside of another application at the same time.

How can I accomplish this? All I can find is the same old movemouse and setcursorpos stuff... as we know that requires the use of your actual mouse/Cursor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking to automate applications. This is done not by faking input but by using an automation API. These days, the preferred one is [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx). This is perfectly accessible from Delphi: [How to use MS UI Automation in Delphi 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12894215).

Comment: Thank you for your input, Im going to look into and see exactley what your talking about