# Is there a way to embed a tab in the CopyToClipboard to paste in tabbed Form fields?

Tags: delphi, clipboarddata

I'm copying multiple fields from a StringGrid to the clipboard with the intent to paste them individually in consecutive fields on the form of a 3rd party program.  Is there a way to have it advance to the next field and write the next value in the clipboard?

I added a tab between the fields when I copied to the clipboard but the result is all the copied fields are pasted (all separated by a tab) to the first field of the form of the 3rd party program.

```
Clipboard.AsText(AdvStringGrid1.Cells[4,ARow] + #9 + AdvStringGrid1.Cells[3,ARow]);
```

It appears that the 3rd party program has tabs set up for the fields on their form, so I'd like the clipboard to copy field 1 and then advance, copy field 2 and then advance.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Well, if someone pasted your example string into one of your form's fields, would your app obligingly parse it and move the bits to the right fields?  IOW, how could anyone answer without knowing the internals of the other app.  Probably your safest bet is to explore GUI Automation.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894215/how-to-use-ms-ui-automation-in-delphi-2009

Comment: Knowledge of the other application is required here. What is it?

Comment: It is a proprietary medical application where users type the information into the fields.  The only thing I know about it is that when the user completes a field she can hit the tab key to advance the cursor to the next field in the form.  I was hoping that I could set up the clipboard with tabs (or something) to simulate the user clicking the tab key.  Unfortunately I can't get any additional information on the other app.  Thank you.

Comment: If you can't find out about the other app, what chance do we have? Best to delete this post I think.

Comment: The clipboard doesn't retain keystrokes - it contains characters. The "Tab" key can be handled two different ways, depending on application design. Either it can insert a tab character, or it can navigate focus to another control. What you copy to the clipboard is the tab character, and it will stay that way no matter what you try to do with it. What you're looking for is more of a macro.

Comment: Nicely put @JerryDodge.

Comment: @Martin just because the *user* can type a tab into the UI to move between UI fields does not mean putting a tab character into *clipboard data* will have the same effect. The app in question would have to explicit parse the clipboard data looking for tabs and act accordingly. Sounds like it does not actually do that. You may need to look into `SendInput()` to simulate keyboard input, or use UI Automation APIs instead

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - this is what i was seeking.  I will investigate the suggestions.